# Multilevel menu using children condition in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, navbar

This navbar has a 1 level dropdown menu. I want to create up to 3 levels but when adding a grandchildren condition to the children it won't work. With this setting, how would I be able to create a 3 level dropdown menu?

Component Header.vue

```
<template>
  <!--  Top menu -->
  <nav
      id="mainNav"
      :class="$route.path==='/home' ? '' : 'bg-primary'"
      class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top"
  >
    <!--      <div class="rtl-layout" @click="addToggleClass()"><a href="javascript:void(0);">RTL</a></div>-->
    <div class="container ">
      <router-link class="navbar-brand" routerLinkActive="active-link" to="/home">
        <!--            <img src="/static/img/zemle-logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="110" height="37">-->
        <h3 class="text-white">Logo</h3>
      </router-link>

      <button
          aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler"
          data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="main" class="navbar-nav ml-auto main-menu list-unstyled">
          <li
              v-for="(menuItem,i) in menus"
              :id="'menuNo'+i"
              :key="i"
              class="parent nav-item"
              @click="menuToggleLink('menuNo'+i);"
          >
            <router-link
                v-if="menuItem.type == 'link'"
                :to="menuItem.state"
                class="nav-link"
                @click.native="removeCollapseInClass();"
            >
              {{ menuItem.name }}
            </router-link>
            <a
                v-if="menuItem.type == 'sub'"
                class="nav-link"
                href="javascript:void(0)"
            >
              {{ menuItem.name }}&nbsp;
              <i :class="menuItem.icon" @click.stop="menuToggle('menuNo'+i)"></i>
            </a>
            <ul
                v-if="menuItem.type == 'sub' && menuItem.children"
                class="sub-menu arrow-up list-unstyled">
              <li
                  v-for="(grandchildItem,i) of menuItem.children"
                  :key="i"
                  class="nav-item"
              >
                <router-link
                    v-if="grandchildItem.type == 'link'"
                    :to="grandchildItem.state"
                    class="nav-link"
                    @click.native="removeCollapseInClass()"
                >
                  {{ grandchildItem.name }}
                </router-link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div
                class="search-form"
                click-outside
            >
                     <span
                         data-target="#search-style-simple"
                         @click="showSearch()"
                     >
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                     </span>
              <div
                  id="search-style-simple"
                  :class="{'search-active': searchactive}"
                  class="module-container"
              >
                <form action="javascript:void(0);" class="search-box" method="get" role="search">
                  <input class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Search" type="search" value=""/>
                  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
              </div><!-- /module-container -->
            </div><!-- /module -->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchactive: false,
      menus: [
        {
          state: "/home",
          name: "Home",
          type: "link"
        },
        {
          state: "",
          name: "Products",
          type: "sub",
          icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
          children: [
            {state: 'apparel', name: 'Apparel', type: "link"},
            {state: 'bathroom', name: 'Bathroom', type: "link"},
            {state: 'bedding', name: 'Bedding', type: "link"},
            {state: 'decorative-details', name: 'Decorative Details', type: "link"},
          ]
        },
        {
          state: "",
          name: "Shop",
          type: "sub",
          icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
          children: [
            {state: 'product-grid', name: 'Product Grid', type: "link"},
            { state: 'product-cart', name: 'Product Cart', type:"link"},
            { state: 'product-checkout', name: 'Product Checkout', type:"link"},
            {state: 'product-detail', name: 'Product Detail', type: "link"}
          ]
        },
        {
          state: "",
          name: "Blog",
          type: "sub",
          icon: 'fa fa-caret-down',
          children: [
            {state: 'blog-column3', name: 'Blog Column1', type: "link"},
            {state: 'blog-masonry3', name: 'Blog Masonry', type: "link"},
            {state: 'blog-sidebar', name: 'Blog Sidebar', type: "link"},
            {state: 'blog-detail', name: 'Blog Detail', type: "link"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.onScrollEvent();
  },
  methods: {
    showSearch() {
      this.searchactive = !this.searchactive;
    },
    menuToggleLink(id) {
      if (document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("open")) {
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("open");
      } else if (!document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("open")) {
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].classList.remove('open');
        }
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("open");
      }
    },
    addToggleClass() {
      document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("rtl-enable");
    },
    removeCollapseInClass() {
      document.getElementById("navbarCollapse").classList.remove('show');
    },
    onScrollEvent() {
      var headerSticky = document.getElementById('mainNav');
      window.onscroll = function () {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
          headerSticky.classList.add("scrollHeader");
        } else {
          headerSticky.classList.remove("scrollHeader");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried modifying the children and adding a grandchildren to it but it won't display the 2nd or 3rd level menu.

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox sample ?

Comment: That would take me time since I have man components but I will try to make one

Comment: You do not have to expose all your components - just the bare minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was able to make a small app but I believe if I am able to implement the 3 level menu there then it should be the same. The CodeSandbox is https://codesandbox.io/s/header-issue-3-level-menu-needed-4vp1v

Comment: I believe that it will be much easier for you to use a 3rd party component - e.g. https://github.com/michitaro/vue-menu

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I wanted to keep the same format and design. Also the 3rd party recommended above does not work on mobile devices. I will try to start a new nabber from scratch.

Comment: Your CodeSandbox example seems not working - the Bootstrap CSS is missing but even when it is there, the menu is always shown in its entirety rather than activated layer by layer on hovering ...

Comment: That is because is missing many sass files that CodeSandbox won't let me add since they are too many. But if the tree of a 3rd level menu can be made then it should display correctly.